# Node module comment-documentation description

Tags: node.js

I have not been able to find a description for how a Node module is documented, like [this module](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files/blob/master/lib/package.js):

```
/**
 * Holds information of the bower package
 *
 * @class Package
 */

/**
 * @constructor
 * @param {Object}              opts
 * @param {PackageCollection}   collection
 */
```

Any tips on a link for a description of this comment-documentation format?

Comment: [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/)

Comment: Perfect! Maybe you could make an answer out of it that I could accept?